# BitBucket HTTPS Clone - Authentication Failed

Tags: git, https, bitbucket

Cloning from BitBucket.

I've Git setup ok, but got this error when cloning via. `https`. I've access rights on BitBucket website, can see all projects including the one I want to clone.

I visited the [website](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-articles/Announcement-Bitbucket-Cloud-account-password-usage-for-Git-over/ba-p/1948231), `https` is no longer supported. **How should I clone?**

**Update:** I need to setup an App Password... brb

Terminal:

```
me@me:~$ git --version
git version 2.25.1
me@me:~$ git config --list
user.name=me
user.email=me@job.com

me@me:~$ git clone https://me@bitbucket.org/foo/bar.git
Cloning into 'bar'...
Password for 'https://me@bitbucket.org': 
remote: Bitbucket Cloud recently stopped supporting account passwords for Git authentication.
remote: See our community post for more details: https://atlassian.community/t5/x/x/ba-p/1948231
remote: App passwords are recommended for most use cases and can be created in your Personal settings:
remote: https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/app-passwords/
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/foo/bar.git/'

me@me:~$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:foo/bar.git
Cloning into 'bar'...
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (104.192.141.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:BLAH.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,104.192.141.1' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

---

Solution

You need to setup an **App Password**.

On Bitbucket, follow these [6 steps](https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-atlassian-account-password-for-bitbucket-api-and-git-activity).

Then, in Terminal:

```
git clone https://USERNAME:APP_PASSWORD@bitbucket.org/username/reposlug.git
```

[Source](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-do-I-use-the-new-app-password-for-command-line-Git/qaq-p/1955078?tempId=eyJvaWRjX2NvbnNlbnRfbGFuZ3VhZ2VfdmVyc2lvbiI6IjIuMCIsIm9pZGNfY29uc2VudF9ncmFudGVkX2F0IjoxNjUxNzY1NTc4MDM5fQ%3D%3D)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbitbucket%5D+recently+stopped+supporting+account+passwords+for+Git+authentication

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To solve this please see [this](https://itsmycode.com/solved-remote-bitbucket-cloud-recently-stopped-supporting-account-passwords-for-git-authentication/)

**Overview of what the link describes:**

> As you pointed out from the error message, from March 1, 2022,
> Bitbucket Cloud users will no longer be able to use their account
> passwords when using Basic authentication for Git over HTTPS.
>
> This can be resolved by switching to App Password from Account
> Password. First, log in to BitBucket and follow the instructions
> specified to create an App Password in BitBucket once it is done set
> the origin URL to use the App Password.